How to get older versions of Intel oneAPI Base/HPC toolkits? (Windows)
I am trying to find a way to download an older version of oneAPI base kit, I have just realized I forgot to install the 32-bit base kit add-on back in time and now I don't have the 32-bit mkl library. I got a work around by installing the new base kit, 32-bit add-on, and hpc kit but I would really like to know why would Intel remove the access to the older versions and if there's any way we can get hold of the older installation files of the tool kits (without having to pay for priority support).
Thank you!
I have searched through Intel website for a way to download the older versions but couldn't find a way.

Not 100% sure of that, but I believe that the ability to download older versions of the products is limited to customers who purchased support. see https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/release-notes/oneapi-supported-product-versions.htm

Yeah, that's what I saw as well, was hoping I missed something and someone would point me the way to get those older versions without having to pay.
